# Can't install on an emachines e725

Tags: wubi

When I install using wubi and choose ubuntu 11.10, i get a purple screen, then a black screen.

Comment: What video card do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot with noacpi and noapic. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options) list of boot options.

Make sure, your windows filesystem is clean (run checkdisk).
If you can, install ubuntu on native linux partition. Use wubi only if you have to.